# Pymongo query normally, but Mongoengine query nothing

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Very strange: Pymongo query normally, but Mongoengine query nothing:

```
class VkWallPostListView(ListView):
    model = VkWallPost
    context_object_name = "vk_list"

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["blog/vk_list.html"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        wallposts = VkWallPost.objects
        if 'all_posts' not in self.request.GET:
            #wallposts = wallposts.filter(text='S')
            wallposts = VkWallPost._get_collection().find({"text":'S'})
        tag = self.request.GET.get('tag', None)
        if tag:
            wallposts = wallposts.filter(tags=tag)

        return wallposts
```

Option `wallposts = VkWallPost._get_collection().find({"text":'S'})` return objects, but the same Mongoengine  `wallposts = wallposts.filter(text='S')`  is not working - empty results, no errors!
The more: i have the same class that query to another collection - there Mongoengine works normally.

Comment: If VkWallPost is your mongoengine model then you can use VkWallPost.objects(text='S') to filter our your objects

Comment: @Rajsubit - maybe you missed this line wallposts = VkWallPost.objects - exactly the same are already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your VkWallPostListView doesn't inherit directly from `mongoengine.Document`. I recently encountered this as well, where an identical model to the database schema didn't return anything when queried when it inherited from something other than the base `Document` class. It turns out, mongoengine adds a hidden field to child class documents called `_cls` and automatically checks for this when querying.

For example:

If I have a class TextHolder that is the base of my class Post

```
class TextHolder(mongoengine.Document):
    text = mongoengine.StringField()
    meta = { 'allow_inheritance' : True,
             'abstract' : True }

class Post(TextHolder):
    user = mongoengine.ReferenceField(User)
```

If I tried to query by Posts that already existed in the database, they will not have the `_cls` field defined in their documents. So, the way to query for documents that do not conform to this standard is to do this.

```
Post.objects(user=user_to_query_by, class_check=False)
```

This will give me all objects ignoring the `_cls` field and not checking for a match with the current model's class name.

Comment: I had the same issue and added `meta = {'allow_inheritance': False}` to the child class (your `Post`) and everything worked as expected afterwards (I did not have to specify `class_check=False` anymore).